# How can I read the data of all nodes at the simultaneously with LoRa

Tags: arduino, communication, receiver, lora

assume that we have 4 [e32 433T30d](https://www.ebyte.com/en/product-view-news.aspx?id=108) nodes we are measuring temp and sending to a center point. as a image atteached. I am using arduino.

[image]

I am using this library with arduino https://github.com/xreef/LoRa_E32_Series_Library

and center point is reading incoming mesages with this code (arduino code)

```
void loop()
    {
    if (e32ttl.available() > 1){
     
    ResponseStructContainer rsc = e32ttl.receiveMessage(sizeof(Message));
    struct Message message = *(Message*) rsc.data;
    Serial.println(message.type);
     
    Serial.println(*(float*)(message.temperature));
    Serial.println(message.message);
    // free(rsc.data);
    rsc.close();
    }
    }
```

How can I read the data of all nodes at the **simultaneously** without the nodes getting mixed up? it looks like reverse broadcast mode. how can achive that without losing data and constantly reading the same point?

Comment: you can only read data sequentially ... the data could be obtained simultaneously

Comment: How can prevent to read same node everytime. For example center point can read with an order such as first node1, than node2....